# ARM GCC removing required code during optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, stm32, compiler-optimization

I have the following code that does a really basic conversion from 16bpp image to a 1bpp image, the code functions as expected until I enable compiler optimizations, at which point I just get a black image.

```
#define RSCALE 5014709
#define GSCALE 9848225
#define BSCALE 1912602

uint16_t _convertBufferTo1bit(uint8_t* buffer, uint16_t size)
{
    uint8_t* dst_ptr = buffer;
    uint8_t* end_ptr = buffer + size;
    uint16_t pos = 0;
    uint8_t r, g, b, i;
    uint32_t lum;

    while(buffer < end_ptr)
    {
        for(i = 8; i > 0; i--)
        {
            r = (*buffer & 0xF8);
            g = ((*buffer & 0x07) << 5);
            buffer += 1;
            g |= (*buffer & 0x03);
            b = ((*buffer & 0x1F) << 3);
            buffer += 1;

            lum = ((RSCALE * r) + (GSCALE * g) + (BSCALE * b));
            if(lum > 0x7FFFFFFF)
            {
                //White
                dst_ptr[pos] |= (1 << (i-1));
            }
            else
            {
                //black
                dst_ptr[pos] &= ~(1 << (i-1));
            }
        }
        pos++;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

When looking at the decompiled assembly I can see that the `if(lum > 0x7FFFFFFF)` statement and all associated calculations have been removed by the compiler. Can someone help me understand why?

`-O0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra`

https://godbolt.org/z/GhPezzh33

`-O1 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra`

https://godbolt.org/z/bn1M4319h

Comment: @RichardCritten It's a zero terminated loop. It should work properly

Comment: Sorry you are absolutely correct. Found something else - remove the last `F` from `lum > 0x7FFFFFFF` and the code generates correctly - still looking into this.

Comment: The compiler has determined that you cannot reach `0x7ffffff`, since `uint8_t` and `int` (your constants) will have common promoted type `int`, which can't represent numbers larger than that. Change your constants to `[value]u`: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mj1as68sq)

Comment: The sum of coefficients isn't 0xffffff or 0x1000000, but 0xfff970. Is it intended?

Comment: Check your coefficients: `g|=*buffer >> 3` ?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Also, the shifts leave a mask of `0xe7` over `g`, instead of contiguous bits.

Comment: @EOF I don't understand why some people make their lives harder for no reasons. :-)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE you're right, that was a silly mistake

Comment: If you want to optimize this a bit (and are willing to work with lower resolution coefficients), this could be converted to `uint16_t a; memcpy(&a, buffer,2);   (a & 0xf11f) * magic_br  + (a & 0x07e0) * magic_g > threshold;`. Also replace the read-modify-write of `dst[pos] |= x` using a temporary. There's no need to have the else branch either, starting with `temp=0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
lum = ((RSCALE * r) + (GSCALE * g) + (BSCALE * b));
if(lum > 0x7FFFFFFF)
```

`RSCALE`, `GSCALE`, and `BSCALE` are `5014709`, `9848225`, and `1912602`, respectively. Assuming `int` is 32 bits in the C implementation being used, these are all `int` constants.

`r`, `g`, and `b` are all of type `uint8_t`, so they are promoted to `int` in the multiplications.

Then `((RSCALE * r) + (GSCALE * g) + (BSCALE * b))` is a calculation entirely with `int` operands producing an `int` result. So the compiler can see that `lum` is assigned the value of an `int` result, and it is entitled to assume the result is in the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`. Further, it can see all operands are nonnegative, and therefore negative results are not possible, reducing the possible range to `0` to `INT_MAX`. This excludes the possibility that assigning a negative value to a `uint32_t` will cause wrapping to a high value. So the compiler may assume `lum > 0x7FFFFFFF` is never true.

The calculation may overflow `int`, and then the behavior is undefined, and the compiler is still allowed to use the assumption.

To correct this, change at least one operand of each multiplication to `unsigned`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Comment: @MikeNorgate Never use anything less than 32bit as local variables, unless you have very good reasons, such as modulo effects. It will even harm performance on ARM in addition to potential bugs. You don't need to compare with 0x7fffff, but just pack the bit 24. This one will make a good practice for NEON if you are interested. Otherwise, there is absolutely no reason for using 32bit coefficients. ARM has 16bit multiply instructions that run twice as fast.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE thanks for the pointers, this is my first time working with ARM so still have some learning to do when it comes to performance

Comment: @MikeNorgate It isn't just for ARM. You should use make more use of local variables. Everytime you pack a bit to the destination, the CPU will read from memory, pack the bit, and write it back, On ANY CPU, because you aren't using a local variable, but access the memory.

Comment: Very well spotted.  By the way, this is caught by `-fsanitize=undefined` or `-ftrapv`.

Comment: @MikeNorgate Your code is also flawed. You are extracting the red channel from the lower byte. I don't understand why you are reading two `uint8` instead of single `uint16`